# Object.defineProperty get set return wrong value

Tags: javascript

Say I have an object instance like this :

```
var objectA = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c" : 3};
```

and in my code I access the property like this:

```
cc.log(objectA.a); // output 1
```

now I want to add a get/set for this object to provide some simple encrypt/decrypt feature:

```
hookSetGet: function (someObject) {
    for (var key in someObject) {
        cc.log("key: " + key);

        // store the origin value before Object.defineProperty
        var pureValue = someObject[key];

        // add a property to store the encrypted value
        var hiddenValueKey = "__" + key;
        someObject[hiddenValueKey] = undefined;

        Object.defineProperty (
            someObject,
            key, 
            {
                set: function (val) {
                    // simulate encrypt
                    this.hiddenValueKey = val + 1;
                    cc.log("hooked set: " + val + " - " + this.hiddenValueKey);
                },
                get: function () {
                    cc.log("hooked get: " + this.hiddenValueKey + " - " + (this.hiddenValueKey - 1));
                    // simulate decrypt
                    return this.hiddenValueKey - 1;
                }
            }
        );

        // trigger set to encrypt
        someObject[key] = pureValue;
    }
}
```

but when I test the function like this:

```
var objectA = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c" : 3};
this.hookSetGet(objectA);

cc.log(objectA.a);
cc.log(objectA.b);
cc.log(objectA.c);
```

I do not get the result I want :

```
key: a
hooked set: 1 - 2
key: b
hooked set: 2 - 3
key: c
hooked set: 3 - 4

hooked get: 4 - 3
3
hooked get: 4 - 3
3
hooked get: 4 - 3
3
```

It seems like even when I call

```
objectA.a
```

I will get the value of

```
objectA.c
```

The problem seems quite simple but I just can not figure out where is wrong.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks :)

UPDATE:

I tried the following code without change the code of hookSetGet :

```
cc.log(objectA.__a);
cc.log(objectA.__b);
cc.log(objectA.__c);
```

and get:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Then I changed the hookSetGet function:

```
set: function (val) {
    // simulate encrypt
    someObject[hiddenValueKey] = val + 1;
    cc.log("hooked set: " + val + " - " + someObject[hiddenValueKey]);
},
get: function () {
    cc.log("hooked get: " + someObject[hiddenValueKey] + " - " + (someObject[hiddenValueKey] - 1));
    // simulate decrypt
    return someObject[hiddenValueKey] - 1;
}
```

I changed all the this.hiddenValueKey to someObject[hiddenValueKey].

and the output is :

```
cc.log(objectA.__a);  // 2   good
cc.log(objectA.__b);  // 3   good
cc.log(objectA.__c);  // 4   good

cc.log(objectA.a);    // hooked get: 4 - 3   still wrong
cc.log(objectA.b);    // hooked get: 4 - 3   still wrong
cc.log(objectA.c);    // hooked get: 4 - 3   still wrong
```

Comment: Is it wise to modify an object while you are enumerating over it?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst: Yes, that shouldn't matter, properties never get iterated twice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dot notation vs bracket notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) and [JavaScript closure inside loops](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. One of them is that `key` and `hiddenValueKey` are set in the scope of the `hookGetSet` function. Therefore whenever you use them, you use the last value in the loop (3 and __c). You can fix this in two ways:

- use `let` instead of `var` to define `key` and `hiddenValueKey` within the loop scope, but that only works in ES6
- use a closure to scope the inside of the loop

The other problem is that inside the properties you use this.hiddenValueKey, which is the same as `this['hiddenValueKey']`, not `this[hiddenValueKey]` as I assume you intended.

Here is code that works (EcmaScript6):

```
hookSetGet : function (someObject) {
    for (let key in someObject) {
        cc.log("key: " + key);

        // store the origin value before Object.defineProperty
        var pureValue = someObject[key];

        // add a property to store the encrypted value
        let hiddenValueKey = "__" + key;
        someObject[hiddenValueKey] = undefined;

        Object.defineProperty(
            someObject,
            key, {
            set : function (val) {
                // simulate encrypt
                this[hiddenValueKey] = val + 1000;
                cc.log("hooked set: " + val + " - " + this[hiddenValueKey]);
            },
            get : function () {
                // simulate decrypt
                var result = this[hiddenValueKey] - 1000;
                cc.log("hooked get: " + this[hiddenValueKey] + " - " + result);
                return result;
            }
        });

        // trigger set to encrypt
        someObject[key] = pureValue;
    }
}
```

and here is same code for classic ES5 Javascript:

```
hookSetGet : function (someObject) {
    for (var k in someObject) {
        (function () {
            var key = k;
            cc.log("key: " + key);

            // store the origin value before Object.defineProperty
            var pureValue = someObject[key];

            // add a property to store the encrypted value
            var hiddenValueKey = "__" + key;
            someObject[hiddenValueKey] = undefined;

            Object.defineProperty(
                someObject,
                key, {
                set : function (val) {
                    // simulate encrypt
                    this[hiddenValueKey] = val + 1000;
                    cc.log("hooked set: " + val + " - " + this[hiddenValueKey]);
                },
                get : function () {
                    // simulate decrypt
                    var result = this[hiddenValueKey] - 1000;
                    cc.log("hooked get: " + this[hiddenValueKey] + " - " + result);
                    return result;
                }
            });

            // trigger set to encrypt
            someObject[key] = pureValue;
        })();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Now everything works just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

So, you wrote this:

```
   Object.defineProperty (
        someObject,
        key, 
        {
            set: function (val) {
                // simulate encrypt
                this.hiddenValueKey = val + 1;
                cc.log("hooked set: " + val + " - " + this.hiddenValueKey);
            },
            get: function () {
                cc.log("hooked get: " + this.hiddenValueKey + " - " + (this.hiddenValueKey - 1));
                // simulate decrypt
                return this.hiddenValueKey - 1;
            }
        }
    );
```

In your getter and setter `this` from `this.hiddenValueKey` refers to your `objectA` Object in all cases, not to each property. So when you want to set a value for each property you're actually over-writing `objectA.hiddenValueKey`. This is why when you try to `get` back the values you only get the last value which was set.

Even though you set `hiddenValueKey` to be unique, in the getter and setter you acess the same property. This is because `this.hiddenValueKey` is the same as writing `this['hiddenValueKey']`. Did you mean to write `this[hiddenValueKey]` ? Even if you do it, you might have some scoping issues with the `hiddenValueKey` always having the latest key value after you exit the loop.

So, you can try this:

```
   Object.defineProperty (
        someObject,
        key, 
        {
            set: function (val) {
                // simulate encrypt
                this[hiddenValueKey] = val + 1;
                cc.log("hooked set: " + val + " - " + this[hiddenValueKey]);
            },
            get: function () {
                cc.log("hooked get: " + this[hiddenValueKey] + " - " + (this[hiddenValueKey] - 1));
                // simulate decrypt
                return this[hiddenValueKey] - 1;
            }
        }
    );
```

But, as I said, you might have to create a closure for the `hiddenValueKey` variable so it will be unique for each property getter and setter.

You can create a closure like this:

```
   (function(hiddenValueKey) {
     Object.defineProperty (
        someObject,
        key, 
        {
            set: function (val) {
                // simulate encrypt
                this[hiddenValueKey] = val + 1;
                cc.log("hooked set: " + val + " - " + this[hiddenValueKey]);
            },
            get: function () {
                cc.log("hooked get: " + this[hiddenValueKey] + " - " + (this[hiddenValueKey] - 1));
                // simulate decrypt
                return this[hiddenValueKey] - 1;
            }
        }
  );
  }(hiddenValueKey));
```